# ModuleNotFoundError when running python script installed via deb created using stdeb

Tags: python, python-3.x, deb

I've build a really simple Python project I'm packaging into a .deb file for installation. I've got the building of .deb working, but when I run my script via it's command, I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

My project structure is as follows:

```
setup.py
hello
  |
  | - __init.py__
  | - hello.py
  | - world.py
```

*setup.py*

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "hello_py",
    version = "1.3",
    author = "Sion Hughes",
    author_email = "",
    description = "It's a simple hello world, but this time with 2 python file",
    license = "",
    url = " ",
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts' : ['hello = hello.hello:main',
        'command-name = hello.hello:main']
    },
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
    ],
)
```

*hello.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import world

def main():
    print("Hello, this is Siôn's python script")
    world.hello()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*world.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def hello():
    print("Hello from another Python file")
```

All runs fine locally, but when I run using `hello` command, I get the following error:

```
# hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hello", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('hello-py==1.3', 'console_scripts', 'hello')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2854, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/hello/hello.py", line 5, in <module>
    import world
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'world'
```

Where am I going wrong to get this working? Thanks in advance.

Update: Forgot to say in the initial post, I want to be able to run the scripts in their local directory for development purposes too, not just always run via installed .deb

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `import world` in hello.py, try using `import .world`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately with this change, the .deb doesn't install, says the `import .world` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @SionHughes Have you tried `from hello import world`?

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'` this time

Comment: @SionHughes And with `from <your_project_directory_name>.hello import world`?